# passenger-install-nginx-module install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, rubygems, passenger

im try to change my webrick to passenger with nginx but when i try 
`passenger-install-nginx-module`
seems everything is alright at first but at the end it comes with this error i tried to Google the problem but some of the post are 
unanswered very much appreciated for the helping thanks to all

```
# sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' --with-http_ssl_module --add-module='/home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/ext/nginx'
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.42.12-1.fc15.i686 i686
checking for C compiler ... found
 + using GNU C compiler
 + gcc version: 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) 
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... found
checking for sendfile() ... found
checking for sendfile64() ... found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... found
checking for crypt_r() ... found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for nobody group ... found
checking for poll() ... found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... found
checking for O_DIRECT ... found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... found
checking for statvfs() ... found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for dlopen() in libdl ... found
checking for sched_yield() ... found
configuring additional modules
adding module in /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/ext/nginx
checking for Math library ... found
 + ngx_http_passenger_module was configured
checking for PCRE library ... found
checking for OpenSSL library ... found
checking for zlib library ... found
creating objs/Makefile
checking for int size ... 4 bytes
checking for long size ... 4 bytes
checking for long long size ... 8 bytes
checking for void * size ... 4 bytes
checking for uint64_t ... found
checking for sig_atomic_t ... found
checking for sig_atomic_t size ... 4 bytes
checking for socklen_t ... found
checking for in_addr_t ... found
checking for in_port_t ... found
checking for rlim_t ... found
checking for uintptr_t ... uintptr_t found
checking for system endianess ... little endianess
checking for size_t size ... 4 bytes
checking for off_t size ... 8 bytes
checking for time_t size ... 4 bytes
checking for setproctitle() ... not found
checking for pread() ... found
checking for pwrite() ... found
checking for strerror_r() ... found but is not working
checking for gnu style strerror_r() ... found
checking for sys_errlist[] ... found
checking for localtime_r() ... found
checking for posix_memalign() ... found
checking for memalign() ... found
checking for mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED) ... found
checking for mmap("/dev/zero", MAP_SHARED) ... found
checking for System V shared memory ... found
checking for struct msghdr.msg_control ... found
checking for ioctl(FIONBIO) ... found
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff ... found
checking for struct dirent.d_namlen ... not found
checking for struct dirent.d_type ... found

Configuration summary
  + using system PCRE library
  + using system OpenSSL library
  + md5: using OpenSSL library
  + sha1 library is not used
  + using system zlib library

  nginx path prefix: "/opt/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/opt/nginx/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/opt/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/opt/nginx/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"

# make
make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/root-passenger-5241/nginx-0.7.67'
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/nginx.o \
    src/core/nginx.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_log.o \
    src/core/ngx_log.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_palloc.o \
    src/core/ngx_palloc.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_array.o \
    src/core/ngx_array.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_list.o \
    src/core/ngx_list.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_hash.o \
    src/core/ngx_hash.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_buf.o \
    src/core/ngx_buf.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_queue.o \
    src/core/ngx_queue.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_output_chain.o \
    src/core/ngx_output_chain.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_string.o \
    src/core/ngx_string.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_parse.o \
    src/core/ngx_parse.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_inet.o \
    src/core/ngx_inet.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_file.o \
    src/core/ngx_file.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_crc32.o \
    src/core/ngx_crc32.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_rbtree.o \
    src/core/ngx_rbtree.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_radix_tree.o \
    src/core/ngx_radix_tree.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_slab.o \
    src/core/ngx_slab.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_times.o \
    src/core/ngx_times.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.o \
    src/core/ngx_shmtx.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_connection.o \
    src/core/ngx_connection.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_cycle.o \
    src/core/ngx_cycle.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_spinlock.o \
    src/core/ngx_spinlock.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_cpuinfo.o \
    src/core/ngx_cpuinfo.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_conf_file.o \
    src/core/ngx_conf_file.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.o \
    src/core/ngx_resolver.c
src/core/ngx_resolver.c: In function ‘ngx_resolver_process_ptr’:
src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1422:32: error: variable ‘qclass’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1422:25: error: variable ‘qtype’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/root-passenger-5241/nginx-0.7.67'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [v3.0.0.pre4](https://rubygems.org/gems/passenger/versions/3.0.0.pre4) of the passenger gem, which was release in September of 2010.

Passenger is now at [v3.0.11](https://rubygems.org/gems/passenger). I'd suggest updating passenger: `gem update passenger` and running `passenger-install-nginx-module` again.